# SQL Server connection not working when release as a signed apk - android

Tags: android, sql-server, jtds

In debug mode, I can connect to mssql server 2016. I'm using [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) jar file to connect android app with mssql.
During generating signed apk, Android Studio said I am missing few class named XADataSource , etc.

Android Studio cannot resolve symbol of the following :

```
import javax.naming.Reference;
import javax.naming.Referenceable;
import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;
import javax.sql.XAConnection;
import javax.sql.XADataSource;
```

When apk generated, android app not connected to mssql, the connection to mssql not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In proguard-rules.pro, I add following,

```
-ignorewarnings

 -keep class * {
     public private *;
 }
```